# Is it possible to return the documents of two collections?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to store the employees appeals in different collections based on their type. But am afraid that I want be able to return the content of those different collections at once, as I used to return the content of a collection as shown in the code below:

```
pendingAppeals = function() {
  return Al.find({status: "Pending"});
}
```

So my concern is, if I have another collection called `Ml`, will I be able to return the content of both `Al` and `Ml` in the same time?

Comment: `Collection.find()` returns a *cursor*. You can return an *array* of cursors from a publication for example. But is this for a helper?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of mongo you are using and meteor has support for it or not. But mongo 3.2 has a aggregate type join which fetches data from multiple collections depending  on your condition. Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

Not really too sure about your data structure, if you could provide an example it would be easier to work with, however take the following example where we have a `students` and a `teachers` collection:

```
> db.students.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03393"), "name" : "bob" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03394"), "name" : "foo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395"), "name" : "bill" }

> db.teachers.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584020e7410ebb5a4ea03396"),
        "name" : "t 1",
        "studentIds" : [
                ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03393"),
                ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395")
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584020ff410ebb5a4ea03397"),
        "name" : "t 1",
        "studentIds" : [
                ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03394"),
                ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395")
        ]
}
```

Then we can use the aggregation framework with `$unwind` and `$lookup` stages:

```
db.teachers.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$studentIds"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "students",
        localField: "studentIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "students"
        }
    }
])
```

and we'll get the following output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584020e7410ebb5a4ea03396"),
        "name" : "t 1",
        "studentIds" : ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03393"),
        "students" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03393"),
                        "name" : "bob"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584020e7410ebb5a4ea03396"),
        "name" : "t 1",
        "studentIds" : ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395"),
        "students" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395"),
                        "name" : "bill"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584020ff410ebb5a4ea03397"),
        "name" : "t 1",
        "studentIds" : ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03394"),
        "students" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("584020b6410ebb5a4ea03394"),
                        "name" : "foo"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584020ff410ebb5a4ea03397"),
        "name" : "t 1",
        "studentIds" : ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395"),
        "students" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("584020b7410ebb5a4ea03395"),
                        "name" : "bill"
                }
        ]
}
```

Refs: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/